# Explain the difference in these function pointer declarations

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-declaration

Please highlight the difference between the following function declarations:

1. `void (*p) (void *a[], int n)`
2. `void *(*p[]) (void *a, int n)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `void (*p) (void *a[], int n)` defines *a pointer to a function that takes a `void*` array and an `int` as parameter*
2. `void *(*p[]) (void *a, int n)` defines *an array of pointers to functions that return a `void*`, and take a `void*` and an `int` as parameter*.

Answer (score 5):

Neither are function declarations, so there's nothing to explain.

Both are, however, declarations of *function pointers*. There is an excellent [tutorial website](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html) that you should consume.

I should also suggest the handy program `cdecl` (or its [online incarnation](http://cdecl.org/)s); perhaps you'd like to give it a shot yourself before someone reveals the answer for you?

<sub>(You need to type `void *(*p[]) (void *, int)` into the website; i.e. no identifiers for the function arguments.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind, I misread the declarations.
Sorry.

The thing is, you're declaring function pointers, not functions as people already pointed out.